# Create Customer Refund from a Return Authorization

Tags: workflow, netsuite

How can I create a Customer Refund record from the Return Authorization form?

I'd like to intercept the action associated with the Refund button on the Return Authorization form, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Short of that I've tried adding a "Customer Refund" button onto the Return Authorization from using a Workflow. That doesn't seem to work, I can never get the button to show on the form. I've added a single "State 1" to the workflow with an Add Button with a label of "Customer Refund" that triggers on "Before Record Load". So far the button never shows up on the form.

Comment: I believe the Refund button only displays if the Return Authorization is Approved and fully Received. What status is the Return Auth in when the button is missing? Why do you want to intercept the native Refund action?

Comment: The Return Auth is in a Pending Refund state. The Refund button is on the form, but instead of creating a Cash Refund I want to create Customer Refund.

Comment: Aha! I think that is controlled by the "Custom Form" selection. I believe by default, there are two standard forms for a Return Authorization: *Standard Return Authorization - Cash* and *Standard Return Authorization - Credit*. The form you select determines the workflow for refunding. Try switching the Custom Form to the *Credit* version.

Comment: Thanks egrubaugh360, that is what I was looking for, I am now getting a customer refund.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from original comment: I think that is controlled by the "Custom Form" selection. I believe by default, there are two standard forms for a Return Authorization: Standard Return Authorization - Cash and Standard Return Authorization - Credit. The form you select determines the workflow for refunding. Try switching the Custom Form to the Credit version